# Drupal Commerce File not issuing licenses

Tags: commerce

My store has been working perfect for the last year and a half. Yesterday I had to manualy add a license file for a user through Store>File Licenses and clicking on the "Add a file license".

Since then every sale that has come through no file licenses has been allocated to them. When I look in the log file, it gives me this error: "Unable to evaluate action commerce_file_license_issue_order." .

When I go into the order under "LICENSE ORDER OPERATIONS" and I select " Sync to current product" and then press Create, it gives me the following error:
"Licenses could not be updated or created for Little Lien. Check the logs for any errors that occurred." Then when I go and look in the logs, it gives me this error: "EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() (line 122 of /home/embrojpq/public_html/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)."

I hope someone can help please!

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a backup you can restore from?  This might take awhile to fix, so I would first restore from backup so the store is running properly.  I would then set up a test server (if you don't have one already) and update all the modules on that server first and attempt to reproduce the error.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem...after 20 sales have gone through without assigning any file licenses ;)

Yesterday before everything went screwed up, I added the zip file extention under Store>Configuration>License Settings in the "Allowed file extentions" and then I also ticked the "LICENSED FILE FIELD SETTINGS" - "Number of values" to unlimited. That one settings stuffed everything up!

When I changed the "Number of values" back to 1, I could go forth and asign the licenses to the purchases that weren't being assigned licenses without eny issues.

Comment: Go ahead and your comment as an answer; on *Drupal Answers*, it is OK to answer your own question if you discover the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem...after 20 sales have gone through without assigning any file licenses ;) Yesterday before everything went screwed up, I added the zip file extention under Store>Configuration>License Settings in the "Allowed file extentions" and then I also ticked the "LICENSED FILE FIELD SETTINGS" - "Number of values" to unlimited. That one settings stuffed everything up! When I changed the "Number of values" back to 1, I could go forth and asign the licenses to the purchases that weren't being assigned licenses without eny issues.